# Using FAL in Extbase correctly

Tags: typo3, extbase, fal

**Domain model**

```
class Image extends AbstractContent {

    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * Gets the image file
     *
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
     */
    public function getFile() {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the image file
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $file
     * @return void
     */
    public function setFile($file) {
        $this->file = $file;
    }
}
```

**Import service fragments**

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceStorage
 */
protected $defaultStorage;

[...]

$this->defaultStorage = ResourceFactory::getInstance()->getDefaultStorage();

[...]

$file = $this->defaultStorage->addFile(
    '/tmp/4711', 
    $this->defaultStorage->getRootLevelFolder(), 
    'foo.jpg', 
    'overrideExistingFile'
);

$falReference = ResourceFactory::getInstance()->createFileReferenceObject(
    array(
        'uid_local' => $file->getUid(),
        'uid_foreign' => uniqid('NEW_'),
        'uid' => uniqid('NEW_'),
    )
);

$reference = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FileReference::class);
$reference->setOriginalResource($falReference);

$content = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Image::class);
$content->setFile($reference);
```

After saving `$content` the image is available through the record and the filemount but the `Ref` column in `BE > FILE > File List`) is `-` and not `>= 1`. So its look like the reference is some how broken. When I'm using the BE to add an image to the record it's all fine. I'm using TYPO3 CMS 7.3-dev.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the hint in the [Slack channel of TYPO3](https://typo3.slack.com/messages/typo3-cms/).

You just need to set `plugin.tx_myext.persistence.updateReferenceIndex = 1` respectively `module.tx_myext.persistence.updateReferenceIndex = 1` and the index will be updated.

Alternatively you could use `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ReferenceIndex::updateRefIndexTable()`.

Answer (score -1):

When I had to use FAL in my extension I found this link:
http://t3-developer.com/extbase-fluid/extensions-erweitern/fal-in-eigenen-extensions/fal-in-typo3-extensions-verwenden/

Since it is in German, I will in the very shortest explain what is done there:

1. extend your data model in ext_tables.sql 
   add a column of some char type (e.g. varchar)
2. add your column to the column section in your TCA array in ext_tables.php

   'mypictures' => array(
               'exclude' => 1,
               'label' => 'My Pictures',
               'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('image', array(
                       'appearance' => array(
                               'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                       ),
                       'minitems' => 0,
                       'maxitems' => 99,
               ), $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']),
       ),
3. Extend your modelfiles. Pay attention to annotations!
4. You can use your media in your fluid template

Comment: This does not answer the question. I did not ask how to use FAL in Extbase. I asked about how to use it correctly regarding the reference index. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Sorry!
Well as I understand it, you would have to annotate the field in your model class file.

Comment: Something like this: @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>

Comment: Nope, see the other answer. What you mention is 1:1 vs. 1:n relationship but this has nothing to do with the questioned problem. ;)

Comment: Ok, it seams I misunderstood the question. Sorry, again.